# Are there shapes other than circles for which all normals point to the center?

Tags: geometry

One interesting property of circles is if you take any point on their boundary and draw a perpendicular to that boundary, it intersects the circle’s center. Are there any other two-dimensional shapes for which this is the case, or is it the only one?

Comment: Presumably, you mean all normals intersect a single point, since in other shapes, "center" might not mean anything.

Comment: I was thinking of the center as the point with x = average x coordinate and y = average y coordinate.

Comment: Well, that's a center of gravity, so it is a kind of center, I guess.